# Way to specify the css path of the application

Tags: asp.net, css

In my asp.net application face some strange problem .When I deploy my application all pages css works fine, When application running in visual studio then some pages css are disconnected . This pages work fine on iis .Why this problem aries? How to solve this problem?

if have any query plz ask.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: have you hardcoded your fully qualified css path? Can you post the code where you declare your css.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Themes for ASP.NET. See if that helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx